# Sort Array to group matching elements but maintain original order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to sort an array of objects so items with similar categories are grouped but not losing original index of categories

I want to sort/group by the category key but keep the order the categories appeared in in the array. There isn't a specific order for the categories.

```
arr = [
  {
    name: "Name 1",
    category: "D Category"
  },
  {
    name: "Name 2",
    category: "A Category"
  },
  {
    name: "Name 3",
    category: "D Category"
  },
  {
    name: "Name 4",
    category: "G Category"
  },
  {
    name: "Name 5",
    category: "A Category"
  }
];
```

attempt doesnt quite work,
it ends up putting items with same categories together but alphabetizes them, which i dont want

```
arr.sort((first, second) => {
      const firstId = first.category;
      const secondId = second.category;

      if (firstId < secondId) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (firstId > secondId) {
        return 1;
      }

      return 0;
});
```

expected result:

```
expectedResult = [
  {
    name: "Name 1",
    category: "D Category"
  },
  {
    name: "Name 3",
    category: "D Category"
  },
  {
    name: "Name 2",
    category: "A Category"
  },
  {
    name: "Name 5",
    category: "A Category"
  },
  {
    name: "Name 4",
    category: "G Category"
  }
];
```

Doing a .sort with comparison partially works where similar categories are together but they end up getting alphabetized which I don't want

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan added my sort attempt that doesnt maintain original order of category appearance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that might work for you. Basically, it does what you're attempting, but introduces an intermediary step of creating a priority map. This map will contain the unique `category` values (from the original data) as keys, with the order they appear as the value. You can then simply base the `sort` logic off of that. My code maybe be more clear than my explaination:

```js
//Original data
const arr = [{
  name: "Name 1",
  category: "D Category",
}, {
  name: "Name 2",
  category: "A Category"
}, {
  name: "Name 3",
  category: "D Category"
}, {
  name: "Name 4",
  category: "G Category"
}, {
  name: "Name 5",
  category: "A Category"
}];

// A priority map so we have a basis for sorting
const orderPriority = arr
  .map(o => o.category)
  .reduce((map, category, idx) => {
    if (map[category] == null) {
      map[category] = idx;
    }
    return map;
  }, {});

// Now implement the sort based on the priorty map we created:
arr.sort((a, b) => orderPriority[a.category] - orderPriority[b.category]);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first use `reduce` method to group them by category and also save each category index and then sort by index and use `flatMap` to get values.

```js
const arr = [{"name":"Name 1","category":"D Category"},{"name":"Name 2","category":"A Category"},{"name":"Name 3","category":"D Category"},{"name":"Name 4","category":"G Category"},{"name":"Name 5","category":"A Category"}]

const grouped = arr.reduce((r, e, index) => {
  if(!r[e.category]) r[e.category] = {index, values: [e]}
  else r[e.category].values.push(e)
  return r;
}, {})

const result = Object.values(grouped)
  .sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index)
  .flatMap(e => e.values)
  
console.log(result)
```

Comment: It stores index on every first occurrence of category and then later on adds to values array with push so order should be guaranteed. So when its sorting, early occurrences of some category will have lower index then some new category found later on so it should sort correctly and then we just flatten the values arrays which also have elements in the correct order as they appear in the original array. Cant be 1000% sure but i think it should work.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan If you found out some scenario where it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed you used `index` :\

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate the array in advance and collect the groups and get them an order value.

```js
var array = [{ name: "Name 1", category: "D Category" }, { name: "Name 2", category: "A Category" }, { name: "Name 3", category: "D Category" }, { name: "Name 4", category: "G Category" }, { name: "Name 5", category: "A Category" }],
    order = 0,
    hash = array.reduce((o, { category }) => (o[category] = o[category] || ++order, o), {});

array.sort(({ category: a }, { category: b }) => hash[a] - hash[b]);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach by using a `Map` and flat the values of it.

```js
var array = [{ name: "Name 1", category: "D Category" }, { name: "Name 2", category: "A Category" }, { name: "Name 3", category: "D Category" }, { name: "Name 4", category: "G Category" }, { name: "Name 5", category: "A Category" }];

array = Array
    .from(array
        .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.category, [...(m.get(o.category) || []), o]), new Map)
        .values()
    )
    .flat();

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: then i hope for an auto delete for just this part.

Answer (score 1):

This solution populates a `Map`, and then flattens the result into an `Array`. The reason I use a `Map` and not an object, is that objects in JavaScript should not really be thought of as ordered.

```js
const arr = [{ name: "Name 1", category: "D Category", other: {} }, 
             { name: "Name 2", category: "A Category", other: {} }, 
             { name: "Name 3", category: "D Category", other: {} }, 
             { name: "Name 4", category: "G Category", other: {} }, 
             { name: "Name 5", category: "A Category", other: {} }]

const collate = ({arr, field}) => 
    [...arr.reduce((acc,o) =>
        (!acc.has(o[field]) 
            ? acc.set(o[field], [o]) 
            : acc.set(o[field], [...acc.get(o[field]), o]),
        acc), new Map).values()].flat()

console.log(collate({arr, field: 'category'}))
```